# Grouping elements from different data

Tags: r

In my work I'm trying to find which of genes usually comes together. So I set up some experiments and now trying to analyze the data. I already wrote a nice script for analyzing it but still it's not enough.

What I want to do this time is to analyze couple of tables and establish which genes are usually together - in the same cluster.

That's my data:

First table:

```
    > dput(tbl_col_clu1[1:20,])
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `52.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `81` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.64209043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.636411741, 0.183490041, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `140.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `189` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84958569, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `222.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.37119221, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `278` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `340` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `397` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `453.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `529` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `580` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `630.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `683.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `735.5` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `784` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.399952462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0.959211661, 1), `832` = c(0, 0.1266780707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2132893016, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.959211661, 1), `882.5` = c(0, 
0.12667807, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.08480435, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0.70163097), `926.5` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `973` = c(0, 0.12621196, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11813646, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.59389934, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0), `1108` = c(0, 0.092444384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115758222, 
0, 0, 0, 0.925835779, 0, 0, 1, 0.303482426, 0.848464317, 0, 0, 
0), `1200` = c(0, 0.120055749, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.150055416, 0, 
0, 0, 0.558015841, 0, 0, 0.796949668, 0.276321753, 1, 0, 0, 0
), Clusters = structure(c(1L, 64L, 45L, 102L, 11L, 77L, 170L, 
55L, 59L, 316L, 316L, 98L, 90L, 77L, 232L, 178L, 101L, 50L, 51L, 
51L), .Label = c("10", "10,13,15", "10,15", "10,15,16", "10,20,21,22,23,24", 
"10,22,23,24", "11", "11,12,13,14,15", "11,12,13,14,15,16", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"12", "12,13", "12,13,14", "12,13,14,15", "12,13,14,15,16", "12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "12,13,15", "12,13,17", 
"13", "13,14", "13,14,15", "13,14,15,16", "13,14,15,16,17", "13,15", 
"13,15,16,17", "14", "14,15", "14,15,16", "14,15,16,17", "14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"14,19", "15", "15,16", "15,16,17", "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24", "15,17", "15,17,24", "15,22,23,24", 
"15,23", "15,24", "16", "16,17", "17", "17,18,19,20", "17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"17,21,22,23,24", "18", "18,19", "18,19,20", "18,19,20,21", "18,19,20,21,22", 
"18,19,20,21,22,23", "18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "18,19,21", "18,19,22,23", 
"18,20", "19", "19,20", "19,20,21", "19,20,21,22", "19,20,21,22,23", 
"19,20,21,22,23,24", "19,20,22", "19,20,22,23", "19,20,22,23,24", 
"19,20,23", "19,21", "19,22", "19,23", "19,24", "2", "2,18,19,20", 
"2,19,20", "2,3,4", "20", "20,21", "20,21,22", "20,21,22,23", 
"20,21,22,23,24", "20,21,23", "20,22", "20,22,23", "20,22,23,24", 
"20,22,24", "20,23", "20,23,24", "20,24", "21", "21,22", "21,22,23", 
"21,22,23,24", "21,23,24", "21,24", "22", "22,23", "22,23,24", 
"22,24", "23", "23,24", "24", "3", "3,10", "3,18,19,20", "3,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,19,20", "3,19,20,21", "3,19,20,22,23,24", "3,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,20,22,23,24", "3,21,23,24", "3,22,23,24", "3,22,24", "3,23", 
"3,23,24", "3,24", "3,4", "3,4,10", "3,4,18,19", "3,4,18,19,20", 
"3,4,18,19,20,21,22,23", "3,4,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "3,4,19,20,21", 
"3,4,21", "3,4,21,22,23", "3,4,21,22,23,24", "3,4,22,23", "3,4,22,23,24", 
"3,4,22,24", "3,4,23,24", "3,4,24", "3,4,5", "3,4,5,10", "3,4,5,10,23,24", 
"3,4,5,20", "3,4,5,22,23,24", "3,4,5,23,24", "3,4,5,24", "3,4,5,6", 
"3,4,5,6,10", "3,4,5,6,20,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7", "3,4,5,6,7,10", 
"3,4,5,6,7,24", "3,4,5,6,7,8", "3,4,5,6,7,8,10", "3,4,5,6,7,8,10,13", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,10,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7,8,12", "3,4,5,6,7,8,15", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7,8,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22,23,24", "3,4,6", "3,4,6,7,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,4,7", "3,4,7,8", "3,5,6,7,8", "3,5,8", "3,7", "3,7,19,20,22,23", 
"4", "4,10", "4,10,24", "4,18,19,20", "4,19,20", "4,20,21,22", 
"4,20,21,22,23,24", "4,20,22,23,24", "4,22,23,24", "4,23,24", 
"4,24", "4,5", "4,5,10", "4,5,10,21", "4,5,10,23,24", "4,5,19,20,21,22,23", 
"4,5,19,20,22,23,24", "4,5,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,20,22,23,24", 
"4,5,22,23,24", "4,5,24", "4,5,6", "4,5,6,10", "4,5,6,10,20,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,19", "4,5,6,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7", "4,5,6,7,10", "4,5,6,7,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8", "4,5,6,7,8,10", "4,5,6,7,8,10,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,10,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,10,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,10,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,10,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,15", "4,5,6,7,8,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,19,20", "4,5,6,7,8,19,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,14,15,16", "4,5,7,9", "4,5,8,22", "4,6", "4,6,7,22,23,24", 
"4,6,7,23,24", "4,6,7,8,15,17", "4,6,7,8,23,24", "4,7", "4,7,20,21", 
"4,7,21,22,23,24", "4,7,8", "4,7,8,22,23,24", "5", "5,10", "5,17", 
"5,18,19,20,21,22,23", "5,19,20,21,22,23,24", "5,20", "5,22,23,24", 
"5,24", "5,6", "5,6,10", "5,6,7", "5,6,7,10", "5,6,7,10,19", 
"5,6,7,22,23,24", "5,6,7,8", "5,6,7,8,10", "5,6,7,8,10,15", "5,6,7,8,10,22,23,24", 
"5,6,7,8,15", "5,6,7,8,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "5,6,7,8,21,22,23,24", 
"5,6,7,8,22,23,24", "5,6,7,8,9", "5,6,7,8,9,10", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13", 
"5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", "5,6,7,8,9,12", "5,6,7,8,9,13", 
"5,7", "5,7,8", "5,8", "6", "6,10", "6,21,22,23", "6,22", "6,22,23,24", 
"6,7", "6,7,10,17", "6,7,22,23,24", "6,7,23,24", "6,7,24", "6,7,8", 
"6,7,8,10", "6,7,8,13,14,15,16,17", "6,7,8,15", "6,7,8,19,20", 
"6,7,8,20,21,22,23,24", "6,7,8,21,22,23,24", "6,7,8,23,24", "6,7,8,9", 
"6,7,8,9,10", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"6,7,8,9,10,15,16", "6,7,8,9,10,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "6,7,8,9,15", 
"6,8", "7", "7,15", "7,15,17", "7,16,18,21", "7,17", "7,19,20", 
"7,19,20,21,22", "7,20,21,22,23,24", "7,20,22,23,24", "7,22,23,24", 
"7,24", "7,8", "7,8,10", "7,8,10,22,23,24", "7,8,13,15", "7,8,14", 
"7,8,15", "7,8,15,16", "7,8,15,23", "7,8,20", "7,8,22", "7,8,23", 
"7,8,9", "7,8,9,10", "7,8,9,13", "7,8,9,15,16,17", "8", "8,10", 
"8,15", "8,17", "8,22", "8,24", "8,9", "8,9,10", "9", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("10", "20", "52.5", "81", "110", 
"140.5", "189", "222.5", "278", "340", "397", "453.5", "529", 
"580", "630.5", "683.5", "735.5", "784", "832", "882.5", "926.5", 
"973", "1108", "1200", "Clusters"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", 
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01220.1", "at1g01320.2", "at1g01420.1", 
"at1g01710.1", "at1g01800.1", "at1g01920.2", "at1g01940.1", "at1g01960.1", 
"at1g02020.2", "at1g02100.2", "at1g02140.1", "at1g02150.1", "at1g02500.2", 
"at1g02560.1", "at1g02880.3", "at1g02920.1", "at1g02930.2"), class = "data.frame")
```

Second table:

```
> dput(tbl_col_clu2[1:20,])
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `52.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `81` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `110` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `140.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `189` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `222.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `278` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `340` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.583163048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0.218194067), `397` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.63953839, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), `453.5` = c(0, 0.66069369, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0.57541627, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.64615661, 0, 0.45209671, 
0, 0, 0, 0.17022498), `529` = c(0, 0.521435654, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.175996209, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.886059888, 0, 0, 0, 0.17022498), `580` = c(0, 
0.437291195, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.20731698, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.719755907, 0, 0, 0, 0.033248127), `630.5` = c(0, 0.52204783, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.48815538, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.82709638, 0, 
0, 0, 0.09539534), `683.5` = c(0, 0.52429838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.59605685, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.27845748, 0.28224351, 0, 0, 0), `735.5` = c(1, 
0.3768651, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.51381348, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.39914361, 
0.22206677, 0, 0, 0), `784` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `832` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.16189002, 0, 0, 0), `882.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `926.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `973` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.86100786, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `1108` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `1200` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Clusters = structure(c(168L, 32L, 246L, 
168L, 81L, 44L, 8L, 44L, 27L, 318L, 81L, 132L, 15L, 3L, 219L, 
32L, 156L, 318L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("10", "10,11", "10,11,12", 
"10,11,12,13", "10,11,12,13,14", "10,11,12,13,14,15", "10,11,12,13,14,15,16", 
"10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
"10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "10,11,12,13,14,16", "10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", 
"10,11,12,13,19", "10,12", "10,12,13", "10,12,13,14", "10,12,13,14,15", 
"10,12,13,14,15,16,17", "10,12,13,15", "10,12,21", "10,13", "10,13,14", 
"10,17,18", "10,20", "11", "11,12", "11,12,13", "11,12,13,14", 
"11,12,13,14,15", "11,12,13,14,15,16", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22", "11,12,13,14,15,16,18", "11,12,13,17,18,19", 
"11,12,14", "11,13", "11,13,14,15,16", "11,15", "12", "12,13", 
"12,13,14", "12,13,14,15", "12,13,14,15,16", "12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24", "12,13,14,15,16,17,19", "12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,21", "12,13,14,15,16,18", "12,13,14,15,17", 
"12,13,14,16,17,19", "12,13,14,18", "12,13,15", "12,13,16", "12,13,16,17,18,19", 
"12,13,16,19", "12,13,17", "12,13,21,22,23", "12,14", "12,14,15", 
"12,14,15,16", "12,14,15,17,19", "12,15", "12,15,16,17", "12,16,17", 
"12,20", "12,21,23", "13", "13,14", "13,14,15", "13,14,15,16", 
"13,14,15,16,17", "13,14,15,16,17,18", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
"13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23", "13,14,15,16,17,19", 
"13,14,15,16,17,21", "13,14,15,16,18,23", "13,14,17", "13,14,19,20,21,22,23", 
"13,14,23,24", "13,15", "13,15,16", "13,15,16,18,19", "13,15,17", 
"13,16,17", "13,17", "13,17,19", "13,19", "13,21", "14", "14,15", 
"14,15,16", "14,15,16,17", "14,15,16,17,18", "14,15,16,17,18,19", 
"14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24", "14,15,16,17,19", "14,15,16,17,19,20", 
"14,15,16,17,19,20,21", "14,15,16,17,22", "14,15,16,19", "14,15,17", 
"14,15,19", "14,17", "14,17,18,19", "14,19", "14,21", "15", "15,16", 
"15,16,17", "15,16,17,18", "15,16,17,18,19", "15,16,17,18,19,20", 
"15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"15,16,17,19", "15,16,17,19,20,21", "15,16,17,19,24", "15,16,17,20,21", 
"15,16,17,21", "15,16,17,23", "15,16,18,19", "15,16,19,20", "15,17", 
"15,18,19,20", "15,18,19,20,21", "15,19", "16", "16,17", "16,17,18", 
"16,17,18,19", "16,17,18,19,20", "16,17,18,19,20,21", "16,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "16,17,19", 
"16,17,19,20", "16,17,19,20,21", "16,17,19,21", "16,17,23", "16,19", 
"17", "17,18", "17,18,19", "17,18,19,20", "17,18,19,20,21", "17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "17,18,19,21", 
"17,19", "17,19,20", "17,19,20,21", "17,19,20,21,22,23,24", "17,19,23", 
"17,20,21", "17,20,21,23", "17,21,22", "17,23", "17,24", "18", 
"18,19", "18,19,20", "18,19,20,21", "18,19,20,21,22", "18,19,20,21,22,23", 
"18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "18,19,20,21,23", "18,20", "19", "19,20", 
"19,20,21", "19,20,21,22", "19,20,21,22,23", "19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"19,20,21,23,24", "19,20,22", "19,21", "19,22", "19,23", "2", 
"2,17", "2,3,4,5,6", "2,3,4,5,6,7", "20", "20,21", "20,21,22", 
"20,21,22,23", "20,21,22,23,24", "20,21,23", "20,21,23,24", "21", 
"21,22", "21,22,23", "21,22,23,24", "21,23", "22", "22,23", "22,23,24", 
"23", "23,24", "24", "3", "3,23,24", "3,4", "3,4,23,24", "3,4,5", 
"3,4,5,6", "3,4,5,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20,21,22,23,24", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,21,22,23,24", 
"3,4,5,6,8,9", "3,4,5,7,8,9,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "3,4,6,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "4", "4,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,19,20,21,22,23,24", "4,21", "4,22,23,24", "4,5,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6", "4,5,6,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9,13", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,19,20,21,22,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9,19,23,24", "4,5,6,7,8,9,23,24", 
"4,5,7,8,9", "4,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"4,8,9,23,24", "5", "5,22,23", "5,6", "5,6,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"5,6,19,20,21,22,23,24", "5,6,24", "5,6,7", "5,6,7,8", "5,6,7,8,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"5,6,7,8,9", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"5,6,7,8,9,15,23,24", "5,6,9", "5,7", "5,8,9", "6", "6,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"6,19,20,21,22,23,24", "6,20,21,22,23,24", "6,21,22,23,24", "6,7", 
"6,7,8", "6,7,8,9", "6,7,8,9,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"6,7,8,9,23,24", "6,7,9", "6,8,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "6,8,9", 
"6,9", "7", "7,14,24", "7,8,9", "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", "7,8,9,20,21,22,23,24", 
"7,8,9,23,24", "7,9", "7,9,10", "8", "8,19,20,21", "8,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"8,9", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "8,9,10,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "8,9,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"8,9,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22", "8,9,19", "8,9,19,20,21,22,23", 
"8,9,21,22", "9", "9,10", "9,10,11,12,13,14", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", 
"9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
"9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", 
"9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19", "9,12", "9,12,13", "9,12,13,14", 
"9,13", "9,13,14,15", "9,13,14,15,16,17", "9,13,14,15,18", "9,14", 
"9,14,15,16", "9,15", "9,15,16,17", "9,16", "9,16,17,18,19,21,22", 
"9,16,17,19", "9,17", "9,17,18", "9,19", "9,19,20", "9,19,20,21", 
"9,19,21", "9,20", "9,20,21", "9,20,21,22", "9,21", "9,22", "9,23"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("10", "20", "52.5", "81", "110", 
"140.5", "189", "222.5", "278", "340", "397", "453.5", "529", 
"580", "630.5", "683.5", "735.5", "784", "832", "882.5", "926.5", 
"973", "1108", "1200", "Clusters"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", 
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01220.1", "at1g01420.1", "at1g01470.1", 
"at1g01800.1", "at1g01910.5", "at1g01920.2", "at1g01980.1", "at1g02020.2", 
"at1g02100.2", "at1g02130.1", "at1g02140.1", "at1g02150.1", "at1g02500.2", 
"at1g02560.1", "at1g02780.1", "at1g02880.3", "at1g02920.1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Third Table:

```
> dput(tbl_col_clu3[1:20,])
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `33.95` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `58.66` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.328143363, 
0.552139556, 0.495919686, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.416266322, 
0.886125103, 1, 1, 0), `84.42` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.327004551, 0, 0, 0, 0.956778355, 1, 0.175277617, 0.240402438, 
0), `110.21` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.151581882, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0.091367379, 0.029316359, 0, 0), `134.16` = c(0.190968551, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.164736594, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.650199285, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.097800974, 0.007393484, 0, 0), `164.69` = c(0.5342874459, 
0, 0.3619993464, 0, 0, 0.1891527151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4926963182, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `199.1` = c(0.866134859, 0, 0.405387979, 
0, 0, 0.274468991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.352737127, 0.170514318, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `234.35` = c(1, 0, 0.446118481, 0, 0, 0.338427523, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.204601923, 0.343919727, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `257.19` = c(0.732231652, 0, 0.666653103, 0, 0, 0.403078017, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.315665123, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `361.84` = c(0.660960044, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0.202578329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.320183046, 0.424361453, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `432.74` = c(0.47961801, 0, 0.48323321, 
    0, 0, 0.25926071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.36362413, 0.43039587, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `506.34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.22943212, 0.19354376, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `581.46` = c(0, 
    0.52783556, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.64407392, 0, 0.70701938, 0, 
    0.2596209, 0.29757967, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `651.71` = c(0, 
    0.32678969, 0, 0.36428195, 0, 0, 0, 0.64951761, 0, 0.80866933, 
    1, 0.18614028, 0.21567888, 0.32813633, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `732.59` = c(0, 0.229023369, 0, 0.312832425, 0, 0, 0, 0.696041374, 
    0, 0.590471454, 0, 0.108699479, 0.187935709, 0.275177957, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.243080694), `817.56` = c(0, 0.25668583, 
    0, 0.4003249, 0, 0, 0, 0.53376606, 0, 0.85524485, 0, 0.22539659, 
    0.27977127, 0.55089774, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `896.24` = c(0, 
    0.31675535, 0, 0.50882005, 0, 0, 0, 0.74705458, 0.12936306, 
    1, 0, 0.1949139, 0.21957859, 0.75063327, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.63346358
    ), `971.77` = c(0, 0.27811949, 0, 0.48419038, 0, 0, 0, 0.8563439, 
    0.39897143, 0.84491933, 0, 0.13935282, 0.17670128, 0.84111004, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1038.91` = c(0, 1, 0, 0.52506752, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0.85617714, 0, 0.13507463, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), Clusters = structure(c(222L, 88L, 237L, 88L, 145L, 
    155L, 143L, 88L, 122L, 88L, 97L, 180L, 260L, 102L, 186L, 
    145L, 149L, 149L, 145L, 106L), .Label = c("10", "10,11", 
    "10,11,12", "10,11,12,13", "10,11,12,13,14", "10,11,12,13,14,15", 
    "10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "10,11,12,14", "10,11,12,14,15", 
    "10,11,12,14,15,16", "10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18", "10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19", 
    "10,11,12,15,16,17", "10,11,14", "10,11,15", "10,11,15,16,17", 
    "10,11,16", "10,11,17", "10,11,20", "10,12", "10,14,15,16", 
    "10,14,15,16,17,18,19", "10,15", "10,15,16", "10,15,16,18", 
    "10,16,19", "10,18,19,20", "10,19", "10,19,20", "10,20", 
    "11", "11,12", "11,12,13", "11,12,13,14", "11,12,13,14,15", 
    "11,12,13,14,15,16", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19", 
    "11,12,14,15", "11,12,14,15,16,17", "11,12,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19", "11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "11,12,18", "11,12,19", "11,12,20", "12", "12,13", "12,13,14", 
    "12,13,14,15", "12,13,14,15,16", "12,13,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "12,14", "12,14,15", "12,14,15,16", 
    "12,14,15,16,17", "12,14,15,16,17,18", "12,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "12,14,15,16,20", "12,14,15,18,19,20", 
    "12,15", "12,16", "12,16,17,18", "12,18,19,20", "12,19,20", 
    "12,20", "13", "13,14", "13,14,15", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "13,16", "13,20", "14", "14,15", "14,15,16", "14,15,16,17", 
    "14,15,16,17,18", "14,15,16,17,18,19", "14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "14,15,16,18", "14,15,17", "14,15,18", "14,16", "14,16,17", 
    "14,16,17,18,19,20", "14,18,19,20", "14,19", "15", "15,16", 
    "15,16,17", "15,16,17,18", "15,16,17,18,19", "15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "15,20", "16", "16,17", "16,17,18", "16,17,18,19", "16,17,18,19,20", 
    "16,17,18,20", "16,17,19", "16,18,19,20", "16,19,20", "17", 
    "17,18", "17,18,19", "17,18,19,20", "17,18,20", "17,19,20", 
    "17,20", "18", "18,19", "18,19,20", "19", "19,20", "2", "2,19,20", 
    "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4,5", "2,3,4,5,11", "2,3,4,5,6", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8", 
    "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", 
    "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "2,4", "2,5", "2,5,6,7", "20", "3", "3,18", "3,4", "3,4,10", 
    "3,4,20", "3,4,5", "3,4,5,6", "3,4,5,6,7", "3,4,5,6,7,8", 
    "3,4,5,6,7,8,9", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11", 
    "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
    "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "3,4,8", "3,4,8,9", "3,5", "3,7", "3,9", "4", "4,5", "4,5,12,13", 
    "4,5,16", "4,5,6", "4,5,6,16,17,18,19,20", "4,5,6,20", "4,5,6,7", 
    "4,5,6,7,8", "4,5,6,7,8,10,11", "4,5,6,7,8,9", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10", 
    "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
    "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17", 
    "4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "4,6,7", "4,7,13", 
    "5", "5,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19", "5,14", "5,14,15,16", "5,16,19", 
    "5,17,18,19,20", "5,18", "5,6", "5,6,7", "5,6,7,10", "5,6,7,8", 
    "5,6,7,8,10", "5,6,7,8,9", "5,6,7,8,9,10", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11", 
    "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14", 
    "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "5,6,7,8,9,16,17,18,19,20", "5,6,8", "5,7,8,9,10", "5,7,8,9,10,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "5,8", "6", "6,7", "6,7,16", "6,7,8", "6,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,17,18", 
    "6,7,8,19", "6,7,8,9", "6,7,8,9,10", "6,7,8,9,10,11", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12", 
    "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
    "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16", "6,7,8,9,10,18,19", "7", "7,10,11,14,15", 
    "7,12", "7,8", "7,8,12", "7,8,9", "7,8,9,10", "7,8,9,10,11", 
    "7,8,9,10,11,12", "7,8,9,10,11,12,13", "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", 
    "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "7,8,9,10,12,15,16,17,18", 
    "7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "8", "8,10", "8,10,20", 
    "8,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "8,16,17", "8,9", "8,9,10", "8,9,10,11", 
    "8,9,10,11,12", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
    "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16", "8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "8,9,10,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "8,9,17", "9", "9,10", "9,10,11", 
    "9,10,11,12", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", 
    "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "9,10,11,12,14,15,16", "9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18", "9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19", 
    "9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,20", 
    "9,10,11,14,15,16,17", "9,10,12,14,15,16,17", "9,10,14,15", 
    "9,11,12", "9,11,12,14", "9,12,14", "9,20"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("10", 
"33.95", "58.66", "84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1", 
"234.35", "257.19", "361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71", 
"732.59", "817.56", "896.24", "971.77", "1038.91", "Clusters"
), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", "at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", 
"at1g01320.2", "at1g01470.1", "at1g01800.1", "at1g01910.5", "at1g01960.1", 
"at1g01980.1", "at1g02150.1", "at1g02470.1", "at1g02500.2", "at1g02560.1", 
"at1g02780.1", "at1g02816.1", "at1g02880.2", "at1g02920.1", "at1g02930.2", 
"at1g03030.1", "at1g03090.2"), class = "data.frame")
```

The last column (`Clusters`) is important for us and the row.names. This column says in which column we can find any abundance for that gene. It doesn't matter for me in which exaclty cluster is gene but which genes come together with it.

Let's use an example:

```
Those genes belong to the same cluster (cluster 5) in data1.
at1g09640.1
at1g07250.1
at1g08200.1
at1g09300.2    ##
at1g09490.2    ## Those
at1g09760.1    ##
at1g09780.1
```

If we analyze other data set (data2). We can see that some of those genes can be found together again. Maybe it's different cluster (cluster 20) or so but they are together and that's most important for me.

```
at1g02880.3
at1g01220.1
at1g09300.2   ## 
at1g09490.2   ## Those
at1g09760.1   ## 
at1g02130.1
```

I have like 15 similar data sets and I would like to be able to ask R: show me genes which can be found together in 15 of 15 data sets or 13 of 15 data sets and so on....

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get stuck?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to start. Which functions could be useful and so on...

Comment: Basically you would need a matrix/data.frame where rows are genes and columns are your data sets (data1, data2...). Value would note if gene is present in given column. Does that sound right?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to bind the data. I just want to find potential cointeractors. So I would like to see how often (in how many data sets) some genes are in the same cluster. If I bind them I will have a one big data set. Don't know if I understand your intention correctly.

Comment: IMO you could improve the question if you provided at least two (or three) of the different data sets instead of only 1 since you want to do something involving several data sets. And you could limit the sample data to a minimal example. Last but not least, the data you show in your example is not the same structure as in your sample data set.. (where are the clusters?). And, to be honest, I don't understand your example: why is `at1g09300.2` in cluster 5? In the data provided, it seems to be in cluster 17 only?

Comment: Ok, the question is clearer to me, looking at your data, do you also consider subsets? E.g, in data1, `at1g02020.2` is alone in clusters `22,23,24`, but `at1g02500.2` is in `4,22,23,24` and `at1g02150.1` in `4,7,8,22,23,24`. Do these appear together in `22,23,44` or only exact matches?

Comment: If it's possible I am interested in both cases (together and exact matches).

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to turn those comma delimited lists into columns- it is much easier to work with them that way. Then, you want to find which genes have the matching columns. Finally, you can aggregate to get totals of how many genes match other genes.

Note that you will have both orders of genes, as well as genes matched with themselves. Also, the "Clusters" column will tell you how many times they were in the same exact set of clusters.

This will run in O(n^2) time, meaning that doubling the number of genes analyzed will quadruple the time. My quick timing tests estimate it would take 15 hours on my computer to do 15 data frames of 2300 rows.

```
library(plyr)

frame_list <- list(tbl_col_clu1, tbl_col_clu2, tbl_col_clu3)

turn_numbers_into_columns <- function(x) {
  # Creates a data.frame that has the group numbers as columns
  x[, strsplit(x$Clusters, ",")[[1]]] <- 1   
  return(x) 
}

get_comparison <- function(current_table) {
  # Creates a comparison data frame for a single input table   
  simplified_frame <- data.frame(
    "gene" = row.names(current_table), 
    "Clusters" = as.character(current_table$Clusters),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  split_f <- adply(simplified_frame, 1, turn_numbers_into_columns)

  #This is the slow line
  comparison_frame <- ddply(split_f, "gene", function(x) {
    ddply(split_f, "gene", function (y) {
      output <- as.data.frame(x == y)
      output$gene <- x$gene
      output$gene2 <- y$gene
      return(output)
    })   
  })
  return(comparison_frame) 
}

combined_frame <- ldply(frame_list, get_comparison)


sum_frame <- aggregate(
  combined_frame[, !(names(combined_frame) %in% c("gene", "gene2"))], 
  by = combined_frame[, c("gene", "gene2")], 
  FUN = sum,
  na.rm = T)

View(sum_frame)
```

If you had consistently the same set of genes and groupings, you could turn everything into arrays, which run faster than data frames, cutting your time by a factor of about six. The part that runs very slowly would be replaced with something like this. It returns 3-dimensional arrays that you could add together.

```
comparison_frame <- aaply(split_f, 1, function(x) {
    print(x)
    output <- aaply(split_f, 1, function (y) {
      output <- array(x == y, c(1, length(x)))
      return(output)
    })  
    return(output)
  })
```

Comment: It gets stuck in this step `combined_frame <- ldply(frame_list, get_comparison)`. I mean by stuck that it's already working for like 2-3h and nothing...

Comment: How big is your real data set? How many rows in each data frame?

Comment: 2300-2600 rows in each data frame (3 data frame in total). Is it possible that it takes so much time ?

Comment: Yes Shaxi it's will take time, because here you are gonna do permutation combination of string comparision with 15 data set each having 2300+ number of records combinations...

Comment: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 88.5 Mb
In addition: There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)` - I got this error after 40 rows with new code.

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Reached total allocation of 4003Mb: see help(memory.size)` - It looks like it eats my memory. Should I try to run this script on the server ?

Comment: More memory will help... you can also run `get_comparison` on one frame at a time, then save it to disk using `save`. That will at least keep you from having all of them in memory while trying to also do calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Throw them into [SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) with Apriori or FPGrowth algorithm. SPMF expects input as file of comma-separated sequences of integers (you may have to convert your data). Each sequence is on separate string:

```
1,2,4,10
3,2,1,11,12
2,5,14,5
```

You invoke it like this:

```
java -jar spmf.jar run FPGrowth sequences.txt output.txt 35% 90%
```

First number is minimal support (how many sets should contain your group to consider it a group). SPMF contains [different algorithms](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=documentation.php) You can try to see which one fits you best.